# USB Webcam to IP Webcam on UBUNTU Server 11.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, stream

I am wanting to install some security and surveillence in the room my ubuntu server occupies.
I have already sorted out the security but was thinking about installing a camera of some sort. I don't really want to fork out the money to buy an IP camera, but I have a USB camera lying around that I have no other use for.

Is it possible, if I have a web address pointed to my server (example.com) for me to access a live stream of my USB camera, connected to my UBUNTU Server (11.04), straight through a port or on a webpage hosted in APACHE?

Cheers
Mike

**EDIT:** The USB Camera is a Logitech Quickcam Go (v-uap41)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in numerous ways.

- `webcamd` is a daemon that can save an image from the camera continuously.  Just make any kind of webpage that repeatedly loads the image and you'll get a "stream".
- `vcl` can be set up to provide a real video stream encoded in the formats you'd like - and then again embedded on the website - or just as a normal video stream that you read with `vcl` somewhere else.  It also supports multicast.
- [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) is a set of services that not only will provide you with a stream - but can detect movement and create alarms as well.
- And many more (if someone consider this list incomplete, I encourage them to add to it).